# Display CCSprites with a delay

Tags: 2d, ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I am a beginner in `cocos2d` and I wanted to display coin `CCSprites` as soon as it moves off the screen with a **5** second delay. So this is what I wrote in my main gameplay layer to add **7** coins in a row:

```
- (void)coinSidewaysRowOne { 
        if (coinSide1 == FALSE)
        {
            coinSide1 = TRUE;
            NSLog(@"coinSide1 = TRUE");
            int originalX = 500;
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                CCSprite *coinHorizontal = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bubble.png"];
                coinHorizontal.position = ccp(originalX, 150);
                originalX += 20;

                [self addChild:coinHorizontal];
                [coinArray addObject:coinHorizontal];
            }
        }
    }
```

And then, in my updateRunning method I added this, so when the coins spawn outside the screen, they move to the left and disappear:

```
// Move coins off the screen and make them move away
    for (CCSprite *coin in coinArray) {
        // apply background scroll speed
        float backgroundScrollSpeedX = [[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] backGroundScrollSpeedX];
        float xSpeed = 1.09 * backgroundScrollSpeedX;

        // move the coin until it leaves the left edge of the screen
        if (coin.position.x > (coin.contentSize.width * (-1)))
        {
            coin.position = ccp(coin.position.x - (xSpeed*delta), coin.position.y);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**
What I've tried doing is adding this below the if statement above:

```
else {
        coin.visible = TRUE;
        coin.position = ccp(500, 150);
     }
```

So right now, when I run this, the coins move in from the right and move off the screen from the left.
How do I make it so that when the coins move to the left and go off the screen, have a five second delay and then have new coins come back to the screen from the right like it originally did.

Comment: What have you tried already? Do you know how to add a delay? Just write out the steps you want to do, then look up how to do each of the steps.

Comment: Check my update for what I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put my logic.

You have `updateRunning` method, in this method you have a logic of move coin at right to left.

Here you need to use `CCMoveTo` Action,

```
// move the coin until it leaves the left edge of the screen
if (coin.position.x > (coin.contentSize.width * (-1)))
{
   [coin runAction:
     [CCSequence actions: // Here set MoveDuration as you need , may be "5";
      [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:MoveDuration position:ccp(coin.position.x - (xSpeed*delta), coin.position.y)],
      [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
         // Here do stuff when your action is performed.
     }],
      nil]];
}
```

And also call your `updateRunning` method with specific time by using `NSTimer`
such like, call `updateRunning`

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(updateRunning) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; /// Set Time interval as you need;
```